# iptables + TEE : too many duplicates

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, mirroring

My setup consist of 3 VMs :

- "SENDER"
- "RECEIVER"
- "SNIFFER"

On "RECEIVER" I'm trying port mirroring with :

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j TEE --gateway "SNIFFER"
```

It's working, however, on "SNIFFER" I receive many times the amount of packets initially sent (for 5 packets transmitted, I get 155 duplicates).

Why?

P.S : It's on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out it was related to packet forwarding. I had to disable forwarding on SNIFFER node (or at least, restrict it) using a command like that:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

If forwarding is enabled, mirrored packets are forwarded back by the SNIFFER node which explains why they appear multiple times in the packets captures.

Hope this will solve your issue.